# Olympus and/or Four-Thirds resources?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, olympus, four-thirds

Can you recommend any books, blogs or websites that are focused on Olympus and/or Four-Thirds (micro and standard) equipment?

Comment: How will we select a "best" answer here? Are all answers equally valid? Do you have a problem that you are trying to address?

Comment: Anyone think this should be a community wiki? Generalized to micro four thirds camera resources?

Answer (score 5):

This is my go-to resource http://www.four-thirds.org/en/microft/.

At this site, you can find up-to-date news about the Micro Four Thirds industry (new cameras, technology breakthroughs, etc). They also lists the different cameras available in the Four Thirds and Micro Four Thirds formats. They appear to be sponsored by Olympus, but give seemingly unbiased information.

Comment: Could you add a couple of words *why* it's your favorite or what kind of info can be found there? Thanks!

Comment: This website has been taken over by OMD Solutions, and is no longer as useful as it was before. A lot of older (but still relevant to 4/3rds) content has been removed.

Comment: Ugh, yep. Sorry to say it's no longer the useful site it once was.

Answer (score 3):

4/3 rumors (http://www.43rumors.com/), while mainly about rumors for new products, also has a good bit of discussion about available lenses and ways to use these cameras.

Answer (score 2):

Thom Hogan of http://www.bythom.com fame is also writing at http://www.sansmirror.com/. I find that he has some good reviews and some good insight as to what 4/3rds is currently good at and where it needs to improve.

Answer (score 1):

The forum section at http://www.dpreview.com/ tends to focus on equipment. Checkout "Olympus DSLR Talk" and "Micro Four Thirds Talk".

-enjoy